# XML file need to open a .exe on my c drive, but the path has a & in it. Fails

Tags: xml, file, syntax, path, character

I am using XML to edit windows Media Center.

I have the following XML code:

```html
<StartMenu>
 <Builtin></Builtin>

 <Custom Title="Games">
  <MenuItem Name="Play Game">
   <Image>Logged Resources\ehres.dll\rcdata\STARTMENU.QUICKLINK.PICTURES.PLAYFAVS.FOCUS.PNG</Image>
   <Program>C:\Users\John & Jane Doe\AppData\Roaming\Game\Game.exe</Program>
    <PlayingDirective>pause</PlayingDirective>
  </MenuItem>
 </Custom>
<StartMenu>
```

What I am supposed to be able to do is run windows media center, I get a special menu item for games and then i am supposed to be able to run the game from there.

If I leave the & in the program path, I don't get the special menu item in WMC.  If I put in %26 the XML runs and I do get the special menu item but when I click on it, it will not pull up the game.  I think because its has the wrong path with the %26.

If I test the XML code with this:

```html
<Program>C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe</Program>
```

it works like it should, pulling up internet explorer.  So I know the code works, I think my username with the & is screwing it up.  I must fix this without changing the user name folder.  That & has to be there.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Program>C:\Users\John &amp; Jane Doe\AppData\Roaming\Game\Game.exe</Program>
```

solves the problem